# How to fix error on background in android?

Tags: android, background

i want to set background of linearlayout with repeating image. 
 i have 2 files.

**main_bg.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/bg"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

and **main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main_bg"
    >
```

and i've bg.png image on folder drawable. 
But Eclipse says there's an error 
**error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/main_bg').**

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place main_bg.xml in drawable folder. That is in res/drawable.

Answer (score 1):

main_bg.xml should be in drawable folder. Looking at the error I guess it's saved somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Android can't find the drawable resource. All drawables (including those defined by XML) should be in res/drawable .